# Powershell script socket connection error when running script via Ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible, connection, ntlm, winrm

This is my hosts file and the details of the server that is used to send information to the actual Active Directory server:

```
[Windows]
10.15.200.130

[Windows:vars]
ansible_user=domainname\username    
ansible_password=passkey
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_port=5985
ansible_winrm_transport=ntlm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation=true
```

This is my powershell script as written in my playbook task:

```
  - name: Run script
    win_powershell: 
      script: |     
        $results = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq 'Jay.W'" -Properties Created,MemberOf,DistinguishedName | Select Name,SamAccountName,Enabled,Created,DistinguishedName,MemberOf
        $results | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users.txt -Width 5000
      error_action: stop
```

When I run the above powershell script task, I get this error:

```
fatal: [10.15.200.130]: FAILED! => {
"changed": true,
"debug": [],
"error": [
    {
        "category_info": {
            "activity": "Get-ADUser",
            "category": "ResourceUnavailable",
            "category_id": 21,
            "reason": "ADServerDownException",
            "target_name": "",
            "target_type": ""
        },
        "error_details": null,
        "exception": {
            "help_link": null,
            "hresult": -2146233088,
            "inner_exception": {
                "help_link": null,
                "hresult": -2146233087,
                "inner_exception": {
                    "help_link": null,
                    "hresult": -2146232800,
                    "inner_exception": {
                        "help_link": null,
                        "hresult": -2146233087,
                        "inner_exception": {
                            "help_link": null,
                            "hresult": -2147467259,
                            "inner_exception": null,
                            "message": "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host",
                            "source": "System",
                            "type": "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException"
                        },
                        "message": "The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:02:00'.",
                        "source": "System.ServiceModel",
                        "type": "System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException"
                    },
                    "message": "The write operation failed, see inner exception.",
                    "source": "System",
                    "type": "System.IO.IOException"
                },
                "message": "The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:02:00'.",
                "source": "mscorlib",
                "type": "System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException"
            },
            "message": "Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.",
            "source": "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management",
            "type": "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADServerDownException"
        },
        "fully_qualified_error_id": "ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser",
        "output": "Get-ADUser : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it \r\ndoes not have the Active Directory Web Services running.\r\nAt line:7 char:12\r\n+ $results = Get-ADUser -Filter \"SamAccountName -eq 'abby.t'\" -Properti ...\r\n+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADServerDownException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser\r\n \r\n",
        "pipeline_iteration_info": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
```

However, when I run the same two PowerShell commands in PowerShell itself, I was able to produce the correct output.

Can someone tell me how do I resolve this socket connection error for NTLM WinRM authentication?

(Update)
Additional information that might be important: The Windows server in my host file, 10.15.200.130, is not the actual Active Directory (AD) server. It has a copy of the AD and the output I get from running the playbook and PowerShell commands in 10.15.200.130 will be reflected on the actual AD server a few minutes later.

I am also able to create users in AD using Ansible's "community.windows.win_domain_user" module. Just that I am having trouble with the "ansible.windows.win_powershell" module for PowerShell script here.

Comment: Where are you setting the port number : ansible_port=5985.  I would try with the server option : -Server 172.0.0.1:5985.

Comment: @jdweng apparently in the inventory as provided by OP in the initial question.

Comment: @Zeitounator : The code works in playbook with sets port number.  Not in PS where port number is not set.

Comment: Hi @jdweng, do you mean add -Server 10.15.200.130:5985 to the PowerShell script?  
$results = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq 'Jay.W'" -Properties Created,MemberOf,DistinguishedName -Server 10.15.200.130:5985  | Select Name,SamAccountName,Enabled,Created,DistinguishedName,MemberOf

Comment: I think either should work since 127.0.0.1 is the local loopback IP address.

Comment: No, it did not work. I still get the exact same set of error messages.

Comment: Oh and I did not mention this but maybe it is important. The Windows server in my host file, 10.15.200.130, is not the actual Active Directory (AD) server even though they are in the same domain. However, it has a copy of the AD server, and the output that I get from running the playbook and PowerShell commands in 10.15.200.130 will be reflected on the actual AD server few minutes later.

Comment: Also, I am able to create users in AD using Ansible's "community.windows.win_domain_user" module